# How do I create firestore rules based on users email domain?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want to use the authenticated user's email domain to restrict access to information in firestore.

The only way I could work out how to do it was like this:

```
match /organization-secrets/{org} {
    allow read: if request.auth.email.split('@')[1] == org
}
```

Since email adresses can have multiple @, this could easily be spoofed with an email that is something like:

```
hacker@bigcorp.com@h4xxor.net
```

Is there another way to restrict access based on domain?

Answer (score 10):

You could restrict the last domain (and make sure that the email is verified). Use String.matches and make sure to include the '$' at the end of the regular expression.

```
match /organization-secrets/{org} {
    allow read: if (request.auth.token.email.matches('.*@yourdomainhere[.]com$') && 
        request.auth.token.email_verified)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about it could be creating a cloud function that triggers on user create. This cloud function could grant the user a custom claim token

then you could use this in your rules

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Answer (score 1):

You can also slice the string & check if the part after @ is equal to your domain name.

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email.split("@")[1] == "@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

With firestore's new let statements, I think it's possible now:

```
function get_email_domain(email_address) {
  let chunks = email_address.split('@');
  return chunks.size() >= 2 ? chunks[chunks.size()-1] : "";
}
```